# Convert the integer value to hex value

Tags: c, hex, decimal, fpga, xilinx

I have this function in xilinx for giving output to Seven segment.

```
int result;
    XIo_Out32(XPAR_SSG_DECODER_0_BASEADDR,  result);
```

The function gets the int result and puts the output to seven segment as a hex value. So basicly, if i give result = 11; I would see A as a result in seven segment. To see a decimal value on sseg, one approach is to change the verilog code behind this and change the whole concept of the sseg. Another approach is to write a function that changes decimal value into a hex value. I've been searching for a good code block for this but it seems that every one of them, prints the values digit by digit with a loop. I need the whole value as a block. Unfortunately i cannot use the C++ libraries so i have primitive C code. Is there any known algorithms for converting?

Comment: How does `11` map to `A` in hexadecimal?

Comment: Also, are you looking for `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", num);`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you want to convert symbol codes from ASCII to the ones from the 7-segment display character set. If so, you may create a simple mapping, maybe an array of codes indexed by ASCII character id. Then, you'll be able to call your function like:

```
XIo_Out32(XPAR_SSG_DECODER_0_BASEADDR,  'A');
```

Be careful to implement the mapping table for the whole ASCII range.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I've got your question wrong. You'll have to manually convert hexadecimal number to an array of decimal symbols. You may do it by dividing your number by increasing powers of 10 (10^0, 10^1, 10^2, etc) and thus get an array of remainders, which is a decimal representation of your number. You may use snprintf as H2CO3 recommends, but I would recommend against it in some of the embedded applications where RAM is limited; you may even be unable to use sprintf-like functions at all.